# R: find value/index which is not in rank

Tags: r, rank

Imaging a vector which should have ordered values, but one or several values are not in order. How can I find the index of the values that break ranks?

I tried to use `diff()`but I couldn't find a way that it works for all different cases. I'm somehow lost with this. Thanks for any help.

E.g. a breking rank element at index 5

```
t <- c(4, 6, 10, 30, 15, 20, 31) # how to find the index of the value 30?
which(diff(t)<0)
> 4
```

this works but, what if the element breaking rank is 2 instead of 30?

```
t <- c(4, 6, 10, 2, 15, 20, 31) # how to find the index of the value 2?
which(diff(t)<0)
> 3
```

or it is the last element

```
t <- c(4, 6, 10, 12, 15, 20, 9) # how to find the index of the value 9?
which(diff(t)<0)
> 6
```

Comment: What programming language is it? You have to few tags assigned to Your question.

Comment: It's R. The tag R was suggested but I didn't choose it. Sorry.